# Is there an algebraic form for the textbook reaction coordinate curves?

Tags: physical-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, free-energy

So here is a curve often used in textbooks to illustrate a reaction coordinate.

[image]

It's a nice short-hand device to learn the relationship between kinetic and thermodynamic parameters that control the progression and equilibrium of chemical reactions.

I was thinking whether there is an analytical expression for that curve, one that I could use to draw several curves like that (using, say, Desmos) for distinct values of free energy contents of reactants and products and activation energies.

Comment: You know they are just some "pretty lines"? OK, there might be somewhere a case where curvature there is meaningful, but probably not in any textbook.

Comment: @Mithoron, yes I know. But I was looking for a way to systematically draw the pretty lines. Perhaps in a way that could be a tad more useful in an educational setting.

Comment: As nice as such a reaction coordinate looks like, it only is a projection (hence, a simplification) of a [potential surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy_surface). Only with two degrees of freedom one can draw the later like a map.

Comment: See Wikipedia article on reaction coordinates, "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_coordinate"

Comment: As has already been pointed out, the exact shape of these curves is usually meaningless. In practice you should calculate it (by calculating the energy $E$ as a function of some *reaction coordinate* $r$, which represents how a combination of bond lengths/angles changes over the course of a reaction), and then you can plot $E(r)$ versus $r$. But, If you just want the shape in this picture, I think you can define the energies $E(r)$ at the three points, and using that $\mathrm{d}E/\mathrm{d}r = 0$ at these points, fit it to a polynomial curve.

Comment: If the reaction is a simple one such as F+H2 then a LEPS potential can be used. This gives a 3D plot of the energy surface from reactants to products and the lowest path between them gives the potential curve you ask about. The LEPS potential is based on the Morse potential with values taken from experimental data. See this post for a plot of a potential https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/170556/why-does-a-symmetric-stretch-mode-not-have-an-imaginary-frequency/170578#170578 Naturally there are any number of empirical mathematical functions that have the shape you show.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a function that works: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cqwgfj2nzt

The general function would be

$$ a \left( \frac{b}{1 - e^{5-x}} - \frac{c}{1 - e^{10-x}} \right)$$

I'm sure you could rearrange this such that the three parameters directly correspond to initial, activation and final energy, but as this is conceptual only anyway, I did not.

Here is an example graph (smoother than the one posted by the OP):

[image]

And here is a Desmos file [with sliders](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6qhghxyn66).

Comment: Well now that's just showing off. I thought a quartic would do the job! :)

Comment: The classic would be a Bézier [spline](https://youtu.be/jvPPXbo87ds).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use matplotlib to plot a smooth line connecting points

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x = np.array([0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9])
y = np.array([0.57, 0.85, 0.66, 0.84, 0.59])

x_new = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 500)

f = interp1d(x, y, kind="quadratic")
y_smooth = f(x_new)

plt.plot(x_new, y_smooth)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: No so simple - maxima aren't in the right points.

Comment: @Mithoron Well, this is just an example that the OP can adjust later. If one wants the right maxima shown on the line, then just return the coordinate of the maxima from the interpolation and add text manually.

Comment: And by this way, we don't need to know any mathematical function.